# Writing a MySQL database find/replace script in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration

I'm currently in the process of redeveloping my bespoke website to a WordPress-driven CMS.

The website I've been working on is simply my existing URL plus `/dev/`, i.e. `http://my.website.com/dev/`.

I'll be moving this website to `http://my.website.com` over the weekend, and as such will need to remove all references to the `/dev/` URL.

What I'd like to do is, basically, a "find and replace" for `/dev` on my database. I can see exactly which tables have this value in, but naturally as per a WordPress install, quite a lot of these fields are serialized data - which a straightforward `dump` > `open with notepad++` > `find & replace` will break.

The code I've developed for this purpose is here:

```
<?php

$look_at[] = array( "table" => "wp_options", "fields" => array( "option_value" ), "id_field" => "option_id" );
$look_at[] = array( "table" => "wp_postmeta", "fields" => array( "meta_value" ), "id_field" => "meta_id" );
$look_at[] = array( "table" => "wp_posts", "fields" => array( "post_content", "guid" ), "id_field" => "ID" );
$look_at[] = array( "table" => "wp_sfmeta", "fields" => array( "meta_value" ), "id_field" => "meta_id" );
$look_at[] = array( "table" => "wp_sfoptions", "fields" => array( "option_value" ), "id_field" => "option_id" );
$look_at[] = array( "table" => "wp_sferrorlog", "fields" => array( "error_text" ), "id_field" => "id" );

for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof ( $look_at ); $i++ ) {
    foreach( $look_at[$i]["fields"] as $field ) {

        $sql = 'SELECT `' . $field . '`, `' . $look_at[$i]["id_field"] . '` FROM  `' . $look_at[$i]["table"] . '`;';
        $res = mysql_query( $sql );

        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {

            $table = $look_at[$i]["table"];
            $id_field = $look_at[$i]["id_field"];
            $old_val = $row[$field];
            $id = $row[$id_field];

            $unserialized_value = @unserialize( $old_val );

            if ( $old_val === 'b:0;' || $unserialized_value !== false )
                $new_val = serialize( str_replace( array( "/dev/", "/dev" ), array( "/", "" ), $unserialized_value ) );
            else
                $new_val = str_replace( array( "/dev/", "/dev" ), array( "/", "" ), $old_val );

            $update_array[] = array( "id_field" => $id_field, "id" => $id, "table" => $table, "key" => $key, "old_val" => $old_val, "new_val" => $new_val );

        }

    }
}

for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $update_array ); $i++ ) {
    if ( $update_array[$i]["old_val"] !== $update_array[$i]["new_val"] )
        $updated_sql .= 'UPDATE ' . $update_array[$i]["table"] . ' SET `' . $update_array[$i]["key"] . '` = \'' . $update_array[$i]["new_val"] . '\' WHERE `' . $update_array[$i]["id_field"] . '` = \'' . $update_array[$i]["id"] . '\';';
}

mysql_query( $updated_sql );

?>
```

---

An example of the serialized data:

```
a:6:{s:5:"width";s:3:"400";s:6:"height";s:3:"530";s:14:"hwstring_small";s:22:"height='96' width='72'";s:4:"file";s:30:"2011/12/Amazonas-English-1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:13:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-125x165.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"125";s:6:"height";s:3:"165";}s:6:"medium";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-339x450.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"339";s:6:"height";s:3:"450";}s:5:"large";s:0:"";s:14:"post-thumbnail";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-125x165.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"125";s:6:"height";s:3:"165";}s:23:"indexleft-species-thumb";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-200x265.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"200";s:6:"height";s:3:"265";}s:13:"species-thumb";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-288x381.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"288";s:6:"height";s:3:"381";}s:17:"indexheader-thumb";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-400x300.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"400";s:6:"height";s:3:"300";s:4:"path";s:38:"2011/12/Amazonas-English-1-400x300.jpg";s:3:"url";s:88:"http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Amazonas-English-1-400x300.jpg";}s:14:"random-thumb-1";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:28:"Amazonas-English-1-56x75.jpg";s:5:"width";s:2:"56";s:6:"height";s:2:"75";}s:14:"random-thumb-2";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:29:"Amazonas-English-1-75x100.jpg";s:5:"width";s:2:"75";s:6:"height";s:3:"100";}s:14:"random-thumb-3";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:29:"Amazonas-English-1-94x125.jpg";s:5:"width";s:2:"94";s:6:"height";s:3:"125";}s:14:"random-thumb-4";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-113x150.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"113";s:6:"height";s:3:"150";}s:14:"random-thumb-5";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:30:"Amazonas-English-1-132x175.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"132";s:6:"height";s:3:"175";}s:13:"d4p-bbp-thumb";s:0:"";}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**

Unfortunately, there are other instances of `/dev/` in other serialized arrays, such as this example:

`'a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:5:"image";s:3:"loc";s:107:"/home/xxxxx/domains/xxxxxxxxx.com/public_html/dev/wp-content/sp-resources/forum-image-uploads/matt/2012/01/";...`

Or,

`a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"data";s:88:"Your search - <b>link:http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/dev/</b> - did not match any documents.  ";...`

As such, I don't think a simple `preg_replace` (or callback) will do the trick, but I guess an advanced one might?

---

My questions are:

1. Is there a simpler way of doing this?!
2. Will the above code run into any problems?

I'm awful at forseeing problems with my code (bad programmer, I do apologise) and as such a little apprehensive about running tests with this code.

---

**FINAL EDIT: WORKING CODE**

Because my SQL dump was nearly `100mb`, I had to use WAMP with unlimited memory.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    $handle = @fopen("amend-this.sql", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
          $newLine = preg_replace_callback('@s:(\d+)(:\\\"[^"]*www.seriouslyfish\.com)/dev@', create_function('$matches', 'return \'s:\'.($matches[1] - 4).$matches[2];'), $buffer);
          $newLine = preg_replace_callback('@s:(\d+)(:\\\"[^\\\"]*/home/sfish/domains/seriouslyfish\.com/public_html)/dev@', create_function('$matches', 'return \'s:\'.($matches[1] - 4).$matches[2];'), $newLine);
          $newLine = str_replace('http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/dev/', 'http://www.seriouslyfish.com/', $newLine);
          $newLine = str_replace('http://www.seriouslyfish.com/dev/', 'http://www.seriouslyfish.com/', $newLine);
          $newLine = str_replace('/dev', '', $newLine);
          file_put_contents( "amended.sql", $newLine, FILE_APPEND );
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

This code put my new SQL file into the same directory (`X:\wamp\www`) for me to manipulate further.

I had a few issues with data-repetition, and there were 67 instances of `/dev` still in the file for some reason but I used [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to sort all of this out and in the end it took me around 45 minutes to search/replace a database of over 90 million characters.

Comment: What are you trying to do with declaring the $look_at[] ?

Comment: Specify the tables/fields to look at when doing the find/replace. There are a number of fields across a number of tables which will never contain any reference to `/dev`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I had the same problem I ran a mysqldump of the database, then opened in a text editor and just search/replaced the values, before using the SQL to create the new database. Quite simple, surprisingly fast,especially for a one off.

As pointed out, you have the problem with serialized data, so you could do a similar thing with a simple PHP file:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/dump.sql", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
      $newLine = preg_replace_callback('@s:(\d+)(:\\\"[^"]*xxxxxxxxxxx\.com)/dev@', create_function('$matches', 'return \'s:\'.($matches[1] - 4).$matches[2];'), $buffer);
      $newLine = preg_replace_callback('@s:(\d+)(:\\\"[^\\\"]*xxxxxxxxxxx\.com/public_html)/dev@', create_function('$matches', 'return \'s:\'.($matches[1] - 4).$matches[2];'), $newLine);
      $newLine = str_replace('http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/dev/', 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/', $newLine);
      echo $newLine;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

**Note:** this works on a mysqldump, if you're testing, you'll need to remove the `\\\` before the `"`s in the `preg_replace_callback`s - this is just mysqldump escaping quotes.

**Also Note:** There are two preg replaces (one for normal URLs and one for server paths), and one str replace for standard URLs left over.

Comment: Hi Leonard. Unfortunately, if I do this, it'll break my serialized data. PHP's `serialize` function counts on the length of the strings its array contains, i.e. `.com/dev/` is 9 characters, `.com` is only 4. PHP will thus fail to recognise the serialized data as being serialized if the format/lengths aren't correct.

Comment: Ahh - If I remember correctly I used dev.domain.tld and changed to www.domain.tld - sorry about that. If I'm honest, my next step would be to see if I can search at a higher level, change the serialized data to have the right length.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do with the PHP code, as I'm not aware of any text editor that could deal with serialized data.

Comment: Feel free to post up an example of the serialized data

Comment: Added alternative PHP to this answer for you

Comment: Hi Leonard. Could you explain how this will retain valid serialized data? Granted your code will replace the serialized information, but I don't understand how it will change the integer length associated with each string (i.e. the `s:88`)?

Comment: It's matching the integer length then the URL, replacing the URL with itself (minus the /dev) and decrementing the integer length by four via a callback function (i.e. strlen('/dev') == 4). tl;dr: it removes /dev, and fixes the integer length.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give it a go.

Comment: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76222957 bytes) in...`. I've tried setting the memory limit higher; no such luck.

Comment: Either set the memory limit *much* bigger (for just this script, as a one off) or use `fopen()`, `fgets()` and `fclose()` instead to loop through the file a line at a time - this should be fine as I don't believe mysqldump inserts will ever wrap to new lines. Example code: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: I've updated my OP with some additional info which I suspect may kill our chances of using a `preg_callback`?

Comment: Updated the PHP - hopefully this will cover the different situations needed. Let me know how it works - I may improve it and turn it in to a tool for migrating wordpress databases if you thyink it's handy.

Comment: Well my friend, you me and WAMP just saved my life. I will give you a bounty to show you happy I am that your code worked! :D

Comment: +1 Thanks for the very helpful script. Just FYI, I ran into issues with the length parameter on `fgets()`. On very long lines, some of the replacements were missed. When I removed that, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There is the serialization fixer wordpress plugin which does it for the non-programmer: http://davidcoveney.com/575/php-serialization-fix-for-wordpress-migrations/

You can also do it [with PHP](http://caritatis.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/fixing-paths-in-drupal-database/).

Also, here is a sample MySQL code which does it:
https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal%20answersmeta/query/80128/sql-search-and-replace

Take care, since this is a very dangerous tool.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use WP CLI for this?

```
wp search-replace https://example.dev https://example.com
```